# Ember.computed.equal returns false on identical strings

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Is there something I don't understand or have I encountered a bug?

```
isCreator: Ember.computed.equal('session.user.id', 'model.user.id'), //false
isCreator2: Ember.computed('session.user.id','model.user.id', function() {  //true
    return this.get('session.user.id') === this.get('model.user.id');
}),
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`Ember.computed.equal` doesn't take two property keys, it takes one property key and one constant value. Taken from [the documentation](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/2.16/functions/@ember%2Fobject%2Fcomputed/equal):

> A computed property that returns true if the provided dependent property is equal to the given value.

If you want to compare two different properties you'll have to write the computed property manually like you've done with `idCreator2`.

Comment: Thank you. How could I miss that.. :) Working too late in the night I guess.

Comment: Whether it's documented or not, this is a horrible and unexpected aspect of `computed.equal()` and leads me to believe that `computed.equal()` should be avoided in general.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ember-awesome-macro's equal instead, which takes two property keys. See https://github.com/kellyselden/ember-awesome-macros#equal.